# Add another "Formats" select to TinyMce 4 in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMce [Style Formats](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#style_formats) to add custom formats to the ""Formats" dropdown. 
The problem is that I have too many styles to add, and I would like to use another "Formats" dropdown, separated from the first one. I know I can nest formats but it's not enough, I want to add two different Dropdown, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best done adding formats to the formatter programmatically and then adding a menu item and trigger the formatter

```
        editor.on( 'Init', function( e ) {
            editor.formatter.register(
                'page-title',
                { 'selector': 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li',wrapper: false, classes : ['giga', 'primary-font'] }
            );

        } );
        editor.addButton( 'typography', {
            text: 'Typography',
            icon: false,
            type: 'menubutton',
            menu: [
                {
                    text: 'Page Title',
                    menu: [
                        {
                            text: '(Giga) 88 Clan pro thin #000000',
                            onclick: function() {
                                editor.formatter.toggle( 'page-title' );
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the style plugin in tinymce3 (in tinymce4 it is part of the tinymce core). You may copy that plugin rename it and configure it to your needs. Then you need to add the plugin to your plugin list and the tinymce button to your button list.

Comment: Where is this defined exactly in tinyMce4

Comment: If I could use the same Formatting engine but with my code it would be easier obvioulsy

Comment: i tinymce it is somewhere in the tinymce core files

Comment: Added a solution that requires no copy/paste